received value must be a mock or spy function
Я бы хотел проверить вызывается ли эндпоинт login после нажатия кнопки submit, но я не знаю как мне "замокать" функцию login
    test('Submitting the form with empty fields', async () => {

        const login = store.dispatch(authApiSlice.endpoints.login.initiate({username: '', password: ''}))
        
        const { getByTestId, findByTestId } = render(
            <Form />
        )
        const firstInput = getByTestId('usernameField')
        const submitButton = await findByTestId('submitBtn')

        expect(firstInput).not.toBeInvalid()

        await act(() => {
            fireEvent.submit(submitButton)
        });
        expect(getByTestId('usernameField')).toBeInvalid()
        expect(getByTestId('passwordField')).toBeInvalid()
        expect(login).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'
import { store } from '../store/store'
import { theme } from '../theme/theme'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


export const AllTheProviders = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <CssBaseline />
          {children}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Provider>
  )
}

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>,
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'
export { customRender as render }

import { IChangeTaskReq, ICreateTaskReq, ITask, IToken, IUser, IUserReq } from "../../types/types";
import { authApi } from "./auth-api";

export const authApiSlice = authApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        login: builder.mutation<IToken, IUserReq>({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: `auth/login`,
                method: 'POST',
                body
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Token', 'Tasks']
        }),
    })
})


export const { useLoginMutation } = authApiSlice

